# AS3 create component using Flash CS4

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, custom-component, flash-v3-components

I would like to create a basic component consisting of a textbox and a label next to it (in other words an InputText and a StaticText).

I only need to set and get the text in the Input textbox, the static text will stay as is.

Any help would be highly appreciated!
Jasco

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds a bit vague.

You could have two TextFields inside a Sprite, something like:

```
package {
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.text.*;
    /**
     * @author georgeprofenza
     */
    public class FormItem extends Sprite {

        private var _label:TextField;
        private var _input:TextField;

        public function FormItem() {
            init();
        }

        private function init():void{
            _label = new TextField();
            _label.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat('Arial',12,0x000000);
            _label.selectable = false;

            _input = new TextField();
            _input.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat('Arial',12,0x000000);
            _input.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;
            _input.border = true;
            _input.x = _label.width + 5;

            addChild(_label);
            addChild(_input);
        }

        public function get labelText():String{
            return _label.text;
        }
        public function get inputText():String{
            return _input.text;
        }
        public function set labelText(text:String):void{
            _label.text = text;
            _input.x = _label.width + 5;
        }
        public function set inputText(text:String):void{
            _input.text = text;
        }
    }
}
```

Or you could go the full length and develop a proper flash component, this where this [long article](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/creating_as3_components.html) will come in handy.

**The [Yahoo! Astra components library](http://developer.yahoo.com/flash/astra-flash/form/) has some [nice components](http://developer.yahoo.com/flash/astra-flash/classreference/com/yahoo/astra/containers/formClasses/FormItem.html) you could use though.**

The 'easiest' version is to use a Label and TextInput component, place them inside a MovieClip and create a Component Definition:

1. Add the Label and TextInput Components in a MovieClip
2. Name the Label instance:

[image: label]

3. Name the TextInput component

[image: input]

4. Right click the Movie Clip in the
   library and select Component
   Definition:

[image: component definition 1]

5. Define the **properties** you want
   to **modify**, like **label** and
   **input** in the Component Definition Panel:

[image: component definition 2]

6. Link the defined properties to the
   components with a bit of
   actionscript:

   if(this.label) labelComponent.text = this.label;
   if(this.input) inputComponent.text = this.input;

Goodluck!

Comment: Thank you George!  I think this latest edit of your's is what I'm after. Will now try and work through it.