# Flash - Creating Components Documentation for Flash CS5

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, documentation, flash-v3-components

is there no official documentation / guide published somewhere on how to create components for Flash CS5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UI Components in Flash CS5 haven't changed since Flash CS3 as far as I've noticed.

Jeff Kamerer wrote a lengthy series on the [Adobe Devnet on creating AS3.0 Components in Flash](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/creating_as3_components.html).

Here are some of the topics covered (via [Robert Penner](http://robertpenner.com/flashblog/archive/2007_09_01_index.html) )

- Set up the layers and frames in your
  component movie clip symbol
- Implement Live Preview for your
  component
- Dispatch events
- Support styles and easily editable
  skins
- Manage drawing with the invalidation
  model
- Manage focus
- Handle keyboard input
- Create a compiled clip shim for your
  ActionScript definitions
- Deploy your component to the
  Components panel

If you're not planning to use the V2 Component architecture, you could just use
**Component Definition** panel to link your class properties to the Component Inspector easily.

[image: component definition panel]

A bit more on this in the slightly related question [AS3 create component using Flash CS4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012519/as3-create-component-using-flash-cs4).

HTH

Comment: wow, where did you find these links?!  lol.  i guess my googling abilities were off today.  yes, these are a huge help.  thanks.  one question, though.  by "V2 Component Architecture" do you mean building components for ActionScript 2.0?

Comment: @TheDarkInI1978 Let's say I'm interested in components too ;) Sorry if "V2 Component Architecture" is misleading. I mean V3, my bad. A few more details on that here: http://www.gskinner.com/blog/archives/2006/09/building_the_v3.html